# Submit button isn't sending everything | Bootstrap

Tags: php, html

My submit button isn't sending all the form data.

I have an index.php with a bootstrap form and a create.php which does an `echo` on my form when it is submitted.

Problem I'm encoutering is is that none of the fields with user input are actually getting sent to my `create.php`, only the default `Radio` is getting sent

```
<?php

?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="form">
    <form action="./create.php" method="post">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/jDiqUAy.jpg" width="20%" heigth="20%">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="nameInput">Naam van uw kat</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nameInput" placeholder="Henkie">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="emailInput">Email address</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="emailInput" placeholder="name@example.com">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputPassword">Wachtwoord</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Bananen123">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="selectOptions">Kleur van uw kat</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="selectOptions">
                <option>Zwart</option>
                <option>Wit</option>
                <option>Oranje</option>
                <option>Zwart met wit</option>
                <option>Grijs</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
            <p>Extras</p>
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="hairRadio" id="hairRadio1" value="long" checked>
            <label class="form-check-label" for="hairRadio1">
                Lang
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="hairRadio" id="hairRadio2" value="short" checked>
            <label class="form-check-label" for="hairRadio2">
                Kort
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input position-static" type="checkbox" id="litterCheckbox" value="">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="litterCheckbox">
                Kattenbak
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Verstuur</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

create.php

```php
<?php

echo var_dump($_POST);
```

Comment: All your form fields need `name` attributes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you didn't define name attribute for other inputs! Each input need name attribute so that it's data can be send with form.

Answer (score 2):

For an input to be sent `name` attribute is required.

Answer (score 2):

`name` attribute for your input is missing. Add that and it should solve the problem